# integrating sproutcore with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sproutcore

## error

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/_sproutcore"
```

## routes.rb

```
 bulk_routes "/api/bulk"
```

## doubt

i did exactly as directed in http://sproutguides-drogus.strobeapp.com/rails.html#authorization , but while doing rails generate bulk:install instead of

```
route  bulk_routes "/api/bulk"
 route  mount Bulk::Sproutcore.new => "/_sproutcore"
create  app/bulk/application_resource.rb
create  config/initializers/bulk_api.rb
```

it just does

```
route  bulk_routes "/api/bulk"
create  app/bulk/application_resource.rb
create  config/initializers/bulk_api.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/drogus/bulk_api, the bulk_api gem is deprecated and no longer maintained which is probably why it isn't working. The developer points to some additional resources that may be useful.